# file upload with geb

Tags: file-upload, geb

Recently I've got the issue with upload file with geb.
Documentation say me that it's impossible to upload file by usual way but exist another way as in the link bellow
http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#file-upload

```
$('form').fieldName = file.absolutePath
```

but after this way carried out I've got the next exception. It's very strange according the geb docs

`No signature of method: java.lang.String.value() is applicable for argument types: ([C) values: [/tmp/template4951246218168115052.pdf]
Possible solutions: valueOf([C), valueOf(boolean), valueOf(char), valueOf(double), valueOf(float), valueOf(int)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.value() is applicable for argument types: ([C) values: [/tmp/template4951246218168115052.pdf]
Possible solutions: valueOf([C), valueOf(boolean), valueOf(char), valueOf(double), valueOf(float), valueOf(int)
    at geb.content.PageContentSupport.propertyMissing(PageContentSupport.groovy:52)
    at geb.Page.propertyMissing(Page.groovy:99)
    at com.avax.functional.specs.client.DigitalSignatureSpec.chose contract and upload some pdf-file(DigitalSignatureSpec.groovy:35)`

Any idea?
I'll be very grateful.
Thanks

Comment: Would you mind editing your question, also showing the corresponding HTML and mentioning the Geb version used? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to ask for a full test, not just one line. I have no idea if your exception really occurs in the line you have shown here or somewhere else later in the test. The browser name/version and WebDriver version used could also be interesting in case your test is okay.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas.
Solved.
Issue was in web driver

Comment: I am not surprised because for me it worked with the upload. ;-) But please, for your next question remember to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With one line of code you are unlikely to get good answers here or anywhere else.